# JPA One To One relationship between two columns (not PK and not FK)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables, one named "Category" and the other "Rule" that are related logically with One to One relationship using a field (code) different than the Primary Key (PK) of table and not phisically managed with a Foreign Key (FK):

```
CATEGORY
    ID (PK) NUMBER
    COD_RULE VARCHAR
    NAME VARCHAR
    .....

RULE
    ID (PK) NUMBER
    CODE VARCHAR
    TYPE VARCHAR
    .....

I haven't on Rule table FK to category ID but only unique constraint (the relation is 1 to 1)
```

Implemented in this way in JPA

```java
 public Category implement Serializable {
   @Id
   @Column (name="ID")
   private Long id;

   @NotNull
   @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name="CODE_RULE" referencedColumnName="CODE", nullable=false)
   private Rule;

   @Column (name="NAME")
   private String  name;

   //Getter and Setter methods
   .......
}

public Rule implement Serializable {
   @Id
   @Column (name="ID")
   private Long id;

   @NotNull    
   @Column (name="CODE")
   private String code;

   @Column (name="TYPE")
   private String  type;

   //Getter and Setter methods
   .......
}
```

I need to:

1. When retrieve Categories obtain also all informations of associated Rule

```sql
SELECT c.*, r.type FROM Category c LEFT OUTER JOIN Rule r WHERE c.CODE_RULE = r.CODE
```

2. When edit Category maintain aligned CODE_RULE with CODE, so If I change CODE_RULE I would yo change automatically the CODE on Rule

```sql
UPDATE Category SET COD_RULE='5A', NAME='Test' WHERE ID=1 
UPDATE Rule SET CODE='5A' WHERE CODE='AB'
```

I see on the specification that:

> There are three cases for one-to-one associations: either the
>   associated entities share the same primary keys values, a foreign key
>   is held by one of the entities (note that this FK column in the
>   database should be constrained unique to simulate one-to-one
>   multiplicity), or a association table is used to store the link
>   between the 2 entities (a unique constraint has to be defined on each
>   fk to ensure the one to one multiplicity).

But with this implementation satisfy point 1. But not the point 2.
Suppose that I've already created Category (on ID = 1) and associated rule,  when I edit category (having CODE_RULE = CODE = "AB") and change the code to "5A":

```java
@PersistentContext
private EntityManager em;
.......
 Category cat = em.find(Category.class, 1L);
 cat.setName("Test");
 cat.getRule().setCode("5A");

 em.merge(cat);
```

I see that the code has been updated on Rule but not in Category:

BEFORE EDIT

```
Category (ID, COD_RULE, NAME) --> (1, AB, First Category)
Rule (ID, CODE, TYPE) --> (10, AB, C)
```

AFTER EDIT

```
Category (ID, COD_RULE, NAME)--> (1, AB, Test)
Rule (ID, CODE, TYPE) --> (10, 5A, C)
```

How can I do this work in JPA? 
Is this type of operation supported in the JPA specification? 
Is there an alternative (i.e. I have to merge before Rule and then Category)?

Comment: If possible, fix your data model instead.  Some data model is tolerable when writing SQLs, but is ugly to map in JPA.  Your case is one example (using a field that can be altered as "foreign key").  If you can't even change your data model for such simple case, to be honest I don't think JPA is going to be helpful in your project

Comment: So, in order to map this in JPA I have to create necessary a FK on CODE field (in the RULE table) other than the unique constraint?

Comment: from my past experience, in order to effectively use JPA, you usually think in the domain model first, and drive the data model.  Patching around the data model usually makes things harder to maintain.  In your case, you said Category and Rule is one to one, does every category always relates to one rule, and every rule always relates to one category? By simply normalization, then why you split them into separate table?

Comment: From your data model, I cannot see it is a one to one relations (it looks more like a many to one, as by the data model, each Category can refer to only 1 Rule, but there is no restriction on how many Category a Rule can be referred by.  Anyway, normally Category table will simply contains Rule's ID as FK, and shouldn't contain Rule's code (remember Normalization?)

Comment: It seems a lot to say... I will simply put it in an answer then...

Comment: The reason why the table are separated is because there are also other different associations on Rule (other types) from other tables. In my case however if I create FK on CODE with unique constraint should solve the problem, is it right?

Comment: If it is one to one, Rule and Category can simply treat it as one single thing and referred by other.  I start thinking it should be a ManyToOne isn't it?!

Comment: I need to have a one-to-one relationship starting always on the owner of the relationship (Category) . When I create category must be created the Rule associated with same code and when I update category rule code the same code should be aligned. I not need a bidirectional association

Comment: do you mean there is also other entity that will create their own "rule"?  If so, my answer still holds.  Rule Code align with Category Code should be your domain logic (though the uniqueness of code is enforced by DB), that whenever you change category's code, update rule accordingly.  Lemme update the answer.  Just bear in mind, in JPA/Hibernate's world, entity's ID should be something never change

Comment: Thanks Adrian, logically your approach is more correct, sure this solve the problem.

Comment: If you consider this as the answer to your question, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your datamodel, it looks more like a Many To One relationship between Category and Rule, given in your data model only restrict each Category can refer to `[0..1]` `Rule`, but not restricting how many `Categories` that a `Rule` can be referred by.

Based on your comment, it seems that you can change the data model.  Normally if it is a ~ToOne relationship, you should have the referring side referring as FK, which looks like this:

(Tables)

```
CATEGORY (
  CATEGORY_ID NUMBER PK,
  CATEGORY_CODE VARCHAR, // Unqiue
  RULE_ID NUMBER FK to RULE,
  ...  (Don't refer by RULE_CODE!!)
)

RULE (
  RULE_ID NUMBER PK,
  RULE_CODE VARCHAR,  // unique, can be updated
  ...
)
```

Entity should look like

```
class Category {
  @Id @Column(name="CATEGORY_ID)
  Long id;

  @ManyToOne // or @OneToOne if you really insist
  @JoinColumn(name="RULE_ID)
  Rule rule;
)
```

(class `Rule` is straight-forward, I will skip)

The HQL you mentioned should be

```
// When retrieving Category together with Rule
from Category c join fetch c.rule
```

for Point 2, as you mentioned in comment, you are trying to align Rule's code with Category's code, when Category's code is updated.  This should be implemented as:

```
class Category {
    //.....
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
        this.rule.setCode(code);
    }
    //....
)
```

---

Base on personal experience, when using JPA, life will be much easier to drive data model base on domain model design.  It should save a lot of problem caused by "data-model that looks tolerable".